# Error 1004 after restart: macro may not be available in this workbook or all macros may be disabled

Tags: vba, excel, runtime-error

I was running a Macro that opens another excel file(.xlsm) and runs a Macro contained in that file.

I restarted my PC and tried to run it. But the code did not work anymore and shown this error:

> **Run-time error 1004**: Cannot run the macro '01.xlsm!ReadCheckBoxes1'.
>
> The macro may not be available in this workbook or all macros may be disabled.

The error comes up when it reaches this line

```
Call Application.Run(Macro1)
```

**Enable all macros is selected and the trust center has a tick in "Trust access to the VBA project object model"**

The full code is below, can you help me please?

```
Sub FileAnalysis()
        
    Dim File As String
    Dim Path As String
    
    Dim Macro1 As String
    Dim Macro2 As String

    Dim b As Object
    
    Dim Ligne As Integer
    
    Dim wb As Workbook
    
    
    Set b = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(7).Buttons(Application.Caller)
        
        With b.TopLeftCell
            Ligne = .Row
        End With
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    
    File = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(7).Cells(Ligne, "B").Text
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(7).Cells(4, 9) = File 'debug
    
    Path = ActiveWorkbook.Path
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(7).Cells(4, 10) = Path 'debug
            
    If Dir(Path & "\" & File) = "" Then
        MsgBox "File doesn't exist."
    Else
        Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Path & "\" & File)
        ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(6).Unprotect ("test")
        Macro1 = File & "!" & "ReadCheckBoxes1"
        Macro2 = File & "!" & "ReadCheckBoxes2"
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(7).Cells(3, 10) = ActiveWorkbook.Name 'debug
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(7).Cells(4, 11) = Macro1 'debug
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(7).Cells(4, 12) = Macro2 'debug
    
        Call Application.Run(Macro1) 'error displayed here
        Call Application.Run(Macro2) 'error displayed here if I comment the previous line
        wb.Close SaveChanges:=True
        
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(7).Cells(Ligne, 4) = "Yes"
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(7).Cells(4, 13) = "Done"
                    
        Application.DisplayFormulaBar = True
        ActiveWindow.DisplayWorkbookTabs = True
        ActiveWindow.DisplayHeadings = True
        ActiveWindow.DisplayGridlines = True
    End If
                
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
    If Application.CommandBars("Ribbon").Height <= 100 Then
        CommandBars.ExecuteMso "MinimizeRibbon"
    End If

    Set wb = Nothing
    Set b = Nothing
           
End Sub
```

Comment: Is the VBA Project protected in the other workbook?

Comment: No it isn't, I've just double checked it

Comment: And the macro runs fine if I open the other file an run it

Comment: Are there spaces or other "odd" characters in the file name? That often causes problems.

Comment: No. Everything is set to have no spaces, I have also double checked and tried to add the ' in the path. but did not work

This is really puzzling me tbf

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea what happened, but after switching off the laptop (proper switch off) everything started to work again.

Restarting did not work (I tried it 3 times), but switching off and on did make it work again.

A relevant change is that the following warning started to show up before continuing:

"Privacy warning: This document contains macros, ActiveX controls, XML expansion pack information, or Web components. These may include personal information that cannot be removed by the Document Inspector"

If anyone has a clue of what could have happened it would be awesome.

cheers

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and renamed the workbook by removing all underscores and dashes from the file name per ChipsLetten's comment above and it worked.